# Concurrent operation of SPI0 and SPI1 on ATmega328PB

Tags: arduino, avr, arduino-uno, atmega

We have been trying to utilise both the SPI available at the ATmega328PB controller.

**The problem we are solving:**

We are trying to interface Ethernet (ENC28J60) on SPI0 bus and    TLE9879 on SPI1 bus.

We are using the standard Ethernet and TLE9879 libraries.

Arduino framework is being used.

**What works:**

Ethernet and TLE9879 work independently on the SPI0 bus and SPI1 bus respectively with Arduino example code.

**Problem faced:**

Ethernet and TLE9879 do not work simultaneously on the SPI0 bus and SPI1 bus with Arduino example code.

**Questions:**

Is there any special settings to be implemented to take the advantage of both the SPI buses simultaneously on ATmega328PB controller?

Any other suggestions will be appreciated.

What we have tried:

We have tried writing a Custom transfer function for SPI1 and kept the SPI0 for Ethernet. (Works independently but not simultaneously)

Feel free to reach us for any clarifications required.

*TLE9879 is an Infineon external library.

Links to the libraries:

We have not modified the library Ethernet. Standard Library is used.
Here are the links to the library.

[Ethernet Library](https://github.com/njh/EtherCard?utm_source=platformio&utm_medium=piohome)

[Project Link: GitHub - ashraful-khan/test_SPI_Ethernet_Motor: Test both SPI ports on ATmega328PB.](https://github.com/ashraful-khan/test_SPI_Ethernet_Motor.git)

SPIo used for ENC28J60 and SPI1 used for TLE9879 1
Note: Test Project was developed using PlatformIO on VS Code.

Comment: You need to show us the code you tried if you want to be helped.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Sure. What code you are looking for? I would be happy to share that. I have edited the question with the code anyway.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Even before that, I would like to know if what I am doing is really possible or not.

Comment: What make you think it is impossible to begin with? Theoretically you don't even need two separate SPI bus, you can run multiple SPI devices on a single bus with two separate chip select lines.

Comment: @hcheung Thanks for your valuable comment. The reason I started to have doubts about its working is that it never follows the order. I mean when I tries to send the message to both the SPI0 & SPI1 bus, the other side of SPI1 bus(slave) does not seem to receive the right data. If we send AB, it receives CD or something else which is random.

Comment: It means that your code somehow didn't switch from one SPI to another SPI, likely didn't manage the CS pin of each SPI correctly. Without your code, we can only guess. Also, SPI is a bidirectional communication, when you clock out one byte, you receive one byte from the slave at the same time.

Comment: @hcheung Much thanks for your valuable comment again. I have edited my post and the project link is pinned there. Can you please have a look and advice to move forward. I would be happy to share any more details.

Comment: @hcheung, you are right in the sense that theoretically, we don't need a different bus for each SPI device and I believe that is possible only when both of the devices have the same setting like clock rate and all. If they have separate settings, it is difficult to use a single SPI line. Isn't that correct too?

Comment: [SPISettings](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/spi/spisettings/) object allows each SPI transaction to have its own clock speed, bit order and mode, this API has been existed since 2014!

Comment: @hcheung, That's was good suggestion. Thanks. We could build on this but have different problems now.

Coming back to the original dual SPI problem, why did you suggest me single bus and not the usage of dual buses. I would be more than happy to bifurcate both the libraries on different SPI busses altogether. What problem do you see in my plan in case I do that?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Any comments?

Comment: Where's the code for your "Custom transfer function" and "Test project"?

Comment: SPI is a bus, meaning that you could put multiple devices on a single bus with each device control by individual Chip Select pin, so in general you don't need two separate SPIs unless you have specific reason. However, there is nothing wrong if you want to have two SPIs...